# Need to isolate Casper tests by spawning new Phantom js object

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

When running all your tests together (im using grunt to do this) How can you spawn a new instance of the phantom object for each test? I have been trying to use

01-routine.js:

```
casper.test.setUp(function() {
    phantom.exit();
});
```

or

```
casper.test.setUp(function() {
    phantom.create();
    casper.echo('setUp');
});
casper.test.tearDown(function() {
    phantom.close();
    casper.echo('tearDown');
});
```

but I dont think either is doing the trick and seem to stop my files from continuing to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CasperJS "process" needs exactly one PhantomJS process. After a CasperJS process is started, you cannot change the PhantomJS process from under it, because CasperJS is actually only an elaborate script that runs inside of PhantomJS.

You will have to run multiple CasperJS processes which will use their own PhantomJS process. How you would do that depends on the way you're running your scripts (bash/jenkins/exec).

Comment: Hey again @ArtjomB. thanks i thought i was missing something like that. You have been a huge help over the last few days.